# Total ring of fractions under base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

For any finite type $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $A$, i.e. $A = \mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]/I$ is it true, that the total ring of fractions $Q(\mathbb{R} \otimes_\mathbb{Q} A) = Q(\mathbb{R}[\mathbf{x}]/I\mathbb{R}[\mathbf{x}])$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \otimes_\mathbb{Q} Q(A)$?

This is in relation to this question:
[Integral closure/normalization under base change](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436876/integral-closure-normalization-under-base-change).

Comment: It is not true with $A=\mathbb{Q}[x]$ : $Q(\mathbb{R}[x])=\mathbb{R}(x)\neq \mathbb{R}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(x)$. Indeed, $\frac{1}{x-\pi}$ does not belong to the latter. Did you mean *finite* algebra (finite type as a $\mathbb{Q}$-module, in other words a finite dimensional algebra ?)

Comment: No. Would have been too good to be true :( Thank you. I would accept this as an answer, if you copy it. Maybe you can also have a look at the referenced question of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. For instance, take $A=\mathbb{Q}[x]$ so that $Q(\mathbb{R}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} A)=\mathbb{R}(x)$ and $\mathbb{R}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}Q(A)=\mathbb{R}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(x)$. They are different because $\frac{1}{x-\pi}$ belong to the former but not to the latter. In fact, they are even not isomorphic as rings because the former is a field while the latter isn't ($x-\pi$ is not invertible).